# java load properties file path unicode

Tags: java, encoding, cmd

See following code, in the main method:

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
String PROP = args[0];
System.out.println("C:/测试".equals(args[0]));
```

I am running the program in Eclipse. 
When running the program, I added

```
C:/测试
```

into the program arguments.

Here is the result:

```
C:/??
false
```

Why it is false? How to add encoding when loading a cmd arguments?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd line are not really relevant, am I right?

Comment: and 'arg' should really be 'args'? it this within the main method?

Comment: You are right. Post has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell should be able to parse those command line arguments and pass it to the Java process using the respective charset. Looks like your dos prompt isn't able to do that.